# How to include avcodec.h in C++ in Fedora

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, include

I have installed `ffmpeg-devel` using dnf, but when including `"libavcodec/avcodec.h"`, g++ tells me

```
a.cpp:1:10: fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My source file is (a.cpp)

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0; 
}
```

I see `/usr/include/ffmpeg/libavcodec/avcodec.h`, so I changed the name to `ffmpeg/libavcodec/avcodec.h`, but then it says

```
/usr/include/ffmpeg/libavcodec/avcodec.h:31:10: fatal error: libavutil/samplefmt.h: No such file or directory
 #include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What should I do to ensure that all the headers are included properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-I` in `g++` to add `/usr/include/ffmpeg/` in the include path solves the problem.

The final program is

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0; 
}
```

The command to compile it is `g++ a.cpp -I /usr/include/ffmpeg`

Comment: Also in cpp files you need to encapsulate the ffmpeg includes in `extern "C" { }`

Answer (score 0):

This `Makefile` is what I use in a project that makes a/v encoding with ffmpeg libraries. Extracted snipped is below :

```
LIBAV_PATH = /path/to/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/

CXXFLAGS += `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBAV_PATH) pkg-config --cflags $(PKG_DEPS)`
LDFLAGS  += `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBAV_PATH) pkg-config --libs $(PKG_DEPS)`

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS_C) $(OBJECTS_CPP)
    @echo "LD\t" $@
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(WFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "CXX\t" $@
    $(CXX) $(WFLAGS) $(OFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Btw, you can use this format for includes:

```
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
```

Hope that helps.